# Selenium WebDriver Java - Selenium finds desired option in "select", but doesn't click it

Tags: java, select, selenium-webdriver

I have this strange issue. I have one Select drop-down list, with empty option selected in the beginning, and try to pick one option from it:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using=".//select[@name='kontakt_l_user_id']")
WebElement przyjecie_select;

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//select[@name='kontakt_l_user_id']")));

przyjecie_select.click();
Select sel = new Select(przyjecie_select);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(przyjecie_select, By.xpath("//option[@value='2112']")));
sel.selectByValue("2112");
```

While the test is running, I can see, that this select drop-down is clicked, the desired option with value "2112" is found, because it is highlighted, but it is not picked and that empty option is still visible.

I tried many things, but the result is the same. I even add:

```
przyjecie_select.click();
    Select sel = new Select(przyjecie_select);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(przyjecie_select, By.xpath("//option[@value='2112']")));
    sel.selectByValue("2112");
```

but that also doesn't work. I'm using 2.53.
You are my only hope!

Comment: What if you just invoke click() on that item as on WebElement?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, which was is pretty simple. 
I used the .click() method on the Select, which was bad. Select automatically find element and click on it, so double click makes the computer confuse. It should look like that:

```
Select sel = new Select(przyjecie_select);
sel.selectByValue("2420");
```

instead of:

```
przyjecie_select.click();
Select sel = new Select(przyjecie_select);
sel.selectByValue("2420");
```

without attempting to click that Select element at first.

Comment: @chunjef He answered his own question with the solution that worked for him... what's the problem with his answer?

Comment: @JeffC: I mistook this answer for an edit. Retracting my previous comment.